# How do you send a message back to the author via dm? - discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

This needs context, the code won't make sense without it.

So basically, theres a chat on our server called 69chat. The bot will delete the message if it does not have 69 on it. I want to make it so that if you ever forget the 69, it will send you the message that you should have sent(just the message + 69). I tried this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  await bot.process_commands(message)
  if message.channel.id == 757140530739150848:
    if '69' in message.content:
      return
    else:
      await message.delete()
    member = message.author
    channel = await member.create_dm()
    await channel.send('Add a 69 on your message! You betray the 69 cult! Do this 3 more times and a kick will be coming your way!')
    await channel.send("Here's what you should have said:")
    await channel.send('{} 69'.format(message))
```

But, it just sent this:

```
Add a 69 on your message! You betray the 69 cult! Do this 3 more times and a kick will be coming your way!
Here's what you should have said:
<Message id=758138294000943134 channel=<TextChannel id=757140530739150848 name='⟫-:laughing:・69-chat' position=22 nsfw=False news=False category_id=746479616054788118> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=726314322565005382 name='' discriminator='5540' bot=False nick=' but 69 (69)' guild=<Guild id=736148508171829259 name='jesser101 Youtube Community!' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=118>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>> 69
```

That's not what I sent.

How do you fix this and send the actual message you sent? Thanks.

Comment: `message` looks like to be an object that you should have get the actual message text from, i.e. `await channel.send('{} 69'.format(message.content))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message` is a [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) object, so to get the content of the message you sent use `message.content`